# two sentences about participles

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, participles, participle-phrases, participial-adjectives

please help me check these two sentences are grammatical or not

The loudly boiling water is very noisy.

The man swimming very fast is my teacher!

My grammar book told me that participle phrases should be put after the nouns, single participle should be put before the nouns.

So are these two sentences correct?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: They are grammatical, though not especially natural. In your first example, "loudly boiling" is a verb phrase premodifying the noun "water". In the second, "swimming fast" is a participial clause postmodifying the noun "man". Participial clauses are semantically similar to relative clauses, cf. "The man who is swimming fast ...".

Comment: I agree that they are both grammatically correct. The first one strikes me as redundant, because it identifies the water as loud and then states that it is noisy.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! But why is it redundant? Can't we say the boiling water is quite noisy?

Answer (score 3):

It is not true that adjectival participle clauses in general cannot precede the noun they modify. Such pre-position is acceptable if any elements modifying the participle fall before it:

> <sup>ok</sup>The loudly boiling water ...
>   <sup>ok</sup>The rapidly swimming man ...
>   <sup>ok</sup>A highly respected teacher ...

What **is** almost always required is that a participle clause in which the participle is **followed** by its own modifier or complement must be placed **after** the noun the clause modifies.

> <sup>#</sup> The boiling loudly water ... → <sup>ok</sup>The water boiling loudly ...
>   <sup>#</sup> The swimming rapidly man ... → <sup>ok</sup>The man swimming rapidly ...
>   <sup>#</sup> A highly respected by his students teacher ... → <sup>ok</sup>A teacher highly respected by his students ...

This is true not just of participles but any adjectival:

> <sup>ok</sup>The available resources ... *but*
>   <sup>#</sup> The available to us resources ... → <sup>ok</sup>The resources available to us ...

<sup>#</sup>  <sub>*designates an unacceptable utterance*</sub>

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind help! In this way, we can say: The totally broken glass or The glass broken totally(but the second one sounds more like a reduced passive sentence) "broken totally" is a phrase. The rule is single participle should be put before nouns, phrases should be put after nouns. But I still saw some single participles can be put after nouns. e.g.: Do you know the books ordered? They decided to change the materials used(they are not phrases right? if they are added with adverbs they are more acceptable, right?)

Comment: @moyeea You've got a good handle on it. By and large we avoid putting adjectivals with leading but no following dependents after the noun, but that's not a hard-and-fast rule: some adjectives and participles are routinely postposed. And passive participles with only adverb modifiers (*totally broken*) tend to precede the noun.

Comment: Thanks so much! But if I say "broken totally" it should be after the nouns am I right? like "the man swimming fast" Besides, "broken" can work as an adjective. In this way, it can be put before nouns, and can be modified with an adverb so we can say" a broken glass". It depends on the world if it is more like an adjective or an adverb. Am I right? Thanks a million!!

Comment: @moyeea You have it exactly.

Comment: I don't think clauses can function as premodifiers in noun phrases. They are just verb phrases, surely?

Comment: @BillJ Depends on where you want to draw the clausal line. You probably wouldn't hesitate to say that *a family burdened by debt* involves a participle clause; what about *a debt-burdened family*?

Comment: Yes, past-participial clause in the first, but compound adjective in the second. Btw, CGEL p444 sect 14.2 is useful for VPs as premodifiers

Comment: @BillJ *CGEL* is pretty vague about what constitutes a clause and what doesn't. Here you have a clear VP--a 'predicate'--with a clearly recoverable 'subject'--what more does it take? Now: if you want to draw a line between attribution and 'predication', I'll be *very* interested, because that's something that's exercising me a lot lately. But *CGEL* isn't helpful on that subject.

Comment: CGEL seems very clear on attributive VPs as NP modifiers, giving reasons why they are not clauses. I'm not clear if you are you saying that "debt-burdened" is a clause?

Comment: @BillJ Once you grant that the 'presence' of an implicit subject is sufficient to describe a bare VP as a clause there's no ground for excluding this VP from the category.

Comment: I don't follow you; what implicit subject? I can't sense a subject-predicate structure here. "Debt-burdened" is not a VP but an adjective as a premodifier. It's clearly an adjective since it can be modified by "very", occur in complex-intransitive clauses as in "The family were very debt-burdened", and occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs like "become" ("The family became quite debt-burdened"). The evidence seems overwhelming to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44429/discussion-between-stoneyb-and-billj).